# A value of type 'Rx<Future<List<SectionsDBStat>>*>*' can't be assigned to a variable of type

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am learning Flutter and GetX.
I have got Model:

```
class SectionsDBStat {

  int notificationsTotalCount;
  int notificationsWaitingForProcessing;
  DateTime notificationsLastArchiveDate;

  SectionsDBStat({
    required this.notificationsTotalCount,
    required this.notificationsWaitingForProcessing,
    required this.notificationsLastArchiveDate
    });

  factory SectionsDBStat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)  {
      return SectionsDBStat(
        notificationsTotalCount: json['notificationsTotalCount'],
        notificationsWaitingForProcessing: json['notificationsWaitingForProcessing'],
        notificationsLastArchiveDate: DateTime.parse(json['notificationsLastArchiveDate'])
      );

    }  

}
```

I am trying to create Getx contoller that receive data from http:

```
class SectionsStatController extends GetxController {
    
    SectionsDBStat sectionsDBStat = Future.value(<SectionsDBStat>).obs;

    getStat() async {
      var value = await http.get('${url}/stat?total');
      if(value.statusCode == 200) {
          Map<String, dynamic> valueMap = jsonDecode(value.body)['data'];
          sectionsDBStat = SectionsDBStat.fromJson(valueMap);
          update();
      } else {
        print("Can't get stat: ${value.statusCode}");
      }

    }

}
```

I am getting an error:

```
A value of type 'Rx<Future<List<SectionsDBStat>>*>*' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SectionsDBStat'.
```

So I should use another type. But what? I tried `final` but got error:

```
'sectionsDBStat' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you using Future, here you are trying to assign `Rx<Future<List<SectionsDBStat>>*>` to `sectionsDBStat` and that is not possible

Replace this line

```dart
SectionsDBStat sectionsDBStat = Future.value(<SectionsDBStat>).obs;
```

with this

```dart
final sectionsDBStat = SectionsDBStat().obs;
```

and then assign it like this

```dart
sectionsDBStat.value = SectionsDBStat.fromJson(valueMap);
```

Comment: thanks for response and welcome to SO! But I am getting error on `SectionsDBStat().obs;` because it's require data to it's constructor.

Comment: try this `final sectionsDBStat = Rx<SectionsDBStat>(null);`